# most general entire functions of the form $f(z)=u(x)+iv(y)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the most general entire functions of the form $f(z)=u(x)+iv(y),$ 
>   where $u$ and $v$ depend only one real variable.

Comment: Are we to assume $x,y$ are respective real and imaginary parts of $z$?

Comment: yes they are so

Comment: I can see unless $f$ is constant it's $x+iy.$ But how can I rigourously prove it?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Riemann conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is entire, then $u$ and $v$ must satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations $u_x=v_y$, $u_y=-v_x$. Under your constraints the second equation is satisfied automatically, and the first gives $u'(x)=v'(y)$, which is possible only if $u'(x)=v'(y)=a$ (independent of $x,y$). Thus $u(x)=ax+b$, $v(y)=ay+c$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So we have the result: **$f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is entire where $u(x,y)=\phi_1(x),v(x,y)=\phi_2(y)$ $\iff u(x,y)=kx+a,v(x,y)=ky+b$ for some $a,b,k\in\mathbb R.$** [$u:(x,y)\mapsto kx+a,$ and $v:(x,y)\mapsto kx+b,$ are continuous on $\mathbb C.$ Also $u,v$ satisfies C-R equation on $\mathbb C.$ Hence $f=u+iv$ is entire. So such $f$ is possible.] Right?

Comment: yes, that's it.